# How to get the name of the calling class in Java?

Tags: java, callstack

I would like some help on this matter,

Example:

```
public class A {
    private void foo() {
        //Who invoked me?
    }
}

public class B extends A {}

public class C extends A {}

public class D {
     C.foo();
}
```

This is basically the scenario. My question is how can method `foo()` know who is calling it?

**EDIT**: Basically I am trying to do a database Layer, and in `class A` I will create a method that will generate SQL statements. Such statements are dynamically generated by getting the values of all the `public` properties of the calling `class`.

Comment: A method which changes it's behaviour based on the class of the caller really does turn object-oriented programming on it's head. How can you test such a class and have it behave the same in the test as in production? There's got to be a better way to implement what you're doing...

Comment: If this is for logging/debug, perhaps you should just use a debugger/tell users to learn a debugger rather than pollute your framework

Comment: This reminds me somehow of the Fortran COME FROM statement http://www.fortran.com/come_from.html

Comment: Please add a note about that you need to use this for geting the public fields (probably through reflection).

Comment: @Thorbjorn: Done that. (sorry if I can't get the funny Scandinavian characters in your name correct)

Comment: This code makes no sense at all.

Comment: Why not just pass the class name to foo?

Answer (score 38):

Easiest way is the following:

```
String className = new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();
```

But in real there should be no need for this, unless for some logging purposes, because this is a fairly expensive task. What is it, the problem for which you think that this is the solution? We may come up with -much- better suggestions.

**Edit**: you commented as follows:

> *basically i'am trying to do a database Layer, and in Class A i will create a method that will generate sql statements, such statements are dynamically generated by getting the values of all the public properties of the calling class.*

I then highly recommend to look for an existing [ORM library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), such as [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org), [iBatis](http://ibatis.apache.org/) or any [JPA implementation](http://java.sun.com/javaee/technologies/persistence.jsp) to your taste.

Comment: basically i'am trying to do a database Layer, and in Class A i will create a method that will generate sql statements, such statements are dynamically generated by getting the values of all the public properties of the calling class.

Comment: Do exceptions fill the stack trace in the constructor? Or only when thrown?

Comment: @Mark: that's really bad design. I would ***deeply*** reconsider it.

Comment: @Peter: `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()` is always `"getStackTrace"`. Guess you can figure out why...

Comment: @Mark, this gives you the NAME of the class but not the INSTANCE.  In other words, WHICH object will you get the public fields from.  You should pass in a data object.

Comment: @Peter: look at source code of `Thread#getStackTrace()`. Right... It does a `new Exception().getStackTrace()`.

Comment: Right. For currentThread it does not call the native dumpThreads but just creates a new Exception. I deleted my wrong comments. Thank you.

Comment: *"But in real there should be no need for this"* I had a rather unusual use case - I wrote a custom `SecurityManager` which needed to allow certain operations from some (trusted) call-sites but not others. The only way to do it was by inspecting the stack.

Comment: This has been done better by others.  I would not recommend doing this.  Both Spring and JPA implementers have done a lot to make working with relational databases easier.  Your probability of improving on either one is nil.

Answer (score 28):

## Java 9: Stack Walking API

[JEP 259](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/259) provides an efficient standard API for stack walking that allows easy filtering of, and lazy access to, the information in stack traces. First off, you should obtain an instance of `StackWalker`:

```
import static java.lang.StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE;
// other imports

StackWalker walker = StackWalker.getInstance(RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE);
```

After that you can call the `getCallerClass()` method:

```
Class<?> callerClass = walker.getCallerClass();
```

Regardless of how you configured the `StackWalker` instance, the `getCallerClass` method will ignore the reflection frames, hidden frames and those are related to `MethodHandle`s. Also, this method shouldn't be called on the first stack frame.

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps for your use case it would make sense to pass the class of the caller into the method, like:

```
public class A { public void foo(Class<?> c) { ... } }
```

And call it something like this:

```
public class B { new A().foo(getClass() /* or: B.class */ ); }
```

Comment: +1 for +pointing out the *right* way to do it. Let's not mess up with stack traces for something like this.

Comment: Yes.  If caller must pursue the basic design which uses reflection to perform the task, let the linkage be clear.  Pass the class, or an instance.

Comment: In general I would agree with you, but if you are creating a framework of the sorts it can become useful

Comment: @mfeingold: name an example that would work better by inspecting the call stack than getting the class as a parameter

Comment: +1, the only reason to use a stack trace is in a debugging scenario.

Comment: Why are you talking about a Class parameter anyway? He needs the Object of type D, so he can read the property values. I think Mark confused Class/Object anyway, or is everything *static* there?

Comment: @mhaller, theoretically you could want to create a new object (say if the object had to have a public no-arg constructor), and it could be called from a static factory.

Answer (score 3):

foo() is private, so the caller will always be in class A.

Comment: Class D wouldn't have compiled.

Answer (score 2):

if you using slf4j as your application logging system.
you can using:

```
Class<?> source = org.slf4j.helpers.Util.getCallingClass();
```

I think it's faster than new Exception().getStackTrace(), since getStackTrace() alaways doing clone stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [StackWalker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.html)

```
private static Class<?> getCallingClass(int skip) {
    StackWalker walker = StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE);
    Optional<? extends Class<?>> caller = walker.walk(frames ->
            frames.skip(skip).findFirst().map(StackWalker.StackFrame::getDeclaringClass)
    );
    return caller.get();
}
```

If you need the class of the calling method use `skip=1`.

Answer (score 0):

From a stack trace: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip124.html

Answer (score 0):

A hacky solution is `sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass`.

```
public void foo() {
    Class<?> caller = sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass();
    // ...
}
```

It is hacky because you have to ensure that the class that calls `Reflection.getCallerClass()` is loaded on the [bootstrap ClassLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395074/what-loads-the-java-system-classloader) for the annotation `@CallerSensitive` (which `getCallerClass` is tagged with) to work. As such, it probably isn't the best solution for a project unless your project happens to use a [Java Agent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) to add your classes to the bootstrap ClassLoader search.

Comment: Another thing to note is that the package `sun.reflect` shows that it is an internal API that is not save to be available in future releases. Ideally one should not rely on classes from those packages.

Answer (score 0):

With the following code, you obtain the first class which generated the stack of calls:

```java
    public String getInvonkingClassName(boolean fullClassNameNeeded){

        StackTraceElement[] stack = new Exception().getStackTrace();
        String className = stack[stack.length-1].getClassName();


        if(!fullClassNameNeeded){
            int idx = className.lastIndexOf('.');
            className = className.substring(idx+1);
        }

        return className;
    }
```

Boolean argument is used to get the full name including package name, or just class name.

Answer (score 0):

#### [StackFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/StackFrame.html)

The state of one method invocation on a thread's call stack. As a thread executes, stack frames are pushed and popped from its call stack as methods are invoked and then return. A StackFrame mirrors one such frame from a target VM at some point in its thread's execution.

```
JVM Stack: From Frame 1 get Frame 2 details
    |                                           |
    |                                           |
    | Class2.function1()             [FRAME 1]  |
    |       executing the instructions          |
    |-------------------------------------------|
    |Class1.method1()                [FRAME 2]  |
    | called for execution Class2.function1()   |
    |-------------------------------------------|
```

> `Throwable::getStackTrace` and `Thread::getStackTrace` return an array of  [StackTraceElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) objects, which contain the class name and method name of each stack-trace element.

`Throwable::getStackTrace` contains the Stack with frames as Frame1(Top Frame) Current method, Frame2 calls Frame1 method for execution.

```java
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = (new Throwable()).getStackTrace();
// Frame1:Log4J.log(), Frame2:CallerClass
```

`Thread::getStackTrace` contains the stack with Frames:
Frame1:Thread.getStackTrace(), Frame2:Current Method, Frame3:Caller Method

```java
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(); //
```

> `sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess()`

```java
sun.misc.JavaLangAccess javaLangAccess = sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess();
StackTraceElement frame = javaLangAccess.getStackTraceElement((new Throwable()), callerFrame-1 ); // Frame0:Log4J.log(), Frame1:CallerClass
System.out.format("SUN - Clazz:%s, Method:%s, Line:%d\n", frame.getClassName(), frame.getMethodName(), frame.getLineNumber());

Throwable throwable = new Throwable();
int depth = javaLangAccess.getStackTraceDepth(new Throwable());
System.out.println("\tsun.misc.SharedSecrets : "+javaLangAccess.getClass() + " - StackTraceDepth : "+ depth);
for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
    StackTraceElement frame = javaLangAccess.getStackTraceElement(throwable, i);
    System.out.format("Clazz:%s, Method:%s, Line:%d\n", frame.getClassName(), frame.getMethodName(), frame.getLineNumber());
}
```

> JDK-internal `sun.reflect.Reflection::getCallerClass` method. It is deprecated, removed in Java9 <sup>[JDK-8021946](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8021946)</sup>

Any way by using Reflection API we can't find the Line Number of Function which it get called.

```java
System.out.println("Reflection - Called from Clazz : "+ Reflection.getCallerClass( callerFrame )); // Frame1:Log4J.log(), Frame2:CallerClass
```

Example:

```
    static boolean log = false;

    public static void log(String msg) {
        int callerFrame = 2; // Frames [Log4J.log(), CallerClass.methodCall()] 
        StackTraceElement callerFrameStack = null;

        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = (new Throwable()).getStackTrace(); // Frame1:Log4J.log(), Frame2:CallerClass
        //StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();// Frame1:Thread.getStackTrace(), Frame2:Log4J.log(), Frame3:CallerClass
        int callerMethodFrameDepth = callerFrame; // Caller Class Frame = Throwable:2(callerFrame), Thread.currentThread:2(callerFrame+1)
        for (int i = 0; i < stackTraceElements.length; i++) {
            StackTraceElement threadFrame = stackTraceElements[i];
            if (i+1 == callerMethodFrameDepth) {
                callerFrameStack = threadFrame;
                System.out.format("Called form Clazz:%s, Method:%s, Line:%d\n", threadFrame.getClassName(), threadFrame.getMethodName(), threadFrame.getLineNumber());
            }
        }

        System.out.println(msg);
        if (!log){
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(callerFrameStack.getClass());
            logger.info(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Log4J.log("Log4J, main");
        Clazz1.mc1();
        Clazz21.mc12();
        Clazz21.mc11();
        Clazz21.mc21();
    }
}

class Clazz1 {
    public static void mc1() {
        Log4J.log("Clazz1 - mc1");
    }
}
class Clazz11 {
    public static void mc11() {
        Log4J.log("Clazz11 - mc11");
    }
    public static void mc12() {
        Log4J.log("Clazz11 - mc12");
        Clazz1.mc1();
    }
}
class Clazz21 extends Clazz11 {
    public static void mc21() {
        Log4J.log("Clazz21 - mc21");
    }
}
```

---

For Java 9 use [Stack Walking API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just answering this because for some reason the above answers started referring to exception handling - the original question had nothing to do with exceptions.

So, instead of trying to determine the caller of the method in question, and specifically to give more information dealing with the creation of a base class that generates SQL statements for its derived classes, here is an OO solution...

1. Make the base class abstract and include abstract methods that return the data it needs to build a sql statement.
2. This would include methods like...

   getColumnList()
   getFromTable()
   getJoinedTables()
   getFilterColumns()
3. The base class then does not care who is calling it because it is going to call up to the derived class for all the details it needs to create the SQL statement.
   The base class knows the derived classes are going to provide the implementation of these methods because they are abstract.

Another way to implement this would be to have a SQLGenerator class that receives an interface with the methods described above and operates on the instances passed to it via those methods.  For this, you would want to have the abstract methods described above moved into the interface, which all of your SQL related classes would implement.

List item

Answer (score -1):

I tried this and it works well. It is because each Java `Object` has access to `getClass()` method which returns the `class` caller and the method name.

```
public Logger logger() {
    return Logger.getLogger(getClass().toString());
}
```

example usage:

```
public DBTable(String tableName) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    loadTableField();
    this.logger().info("done");
}
```

sample output log using `java.util.logging.Logger`

> Feb 01, 2017 11:14:50 PM rmg.data.model.DBTable (init) INFO: done

Answer (score -2):

Maybe an answer is

```
public class CallerMain {

  public void foo(){
    System.out.println("CallerMain - foo");
    System.out.println(this.getClass()); //output- callerMain
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    CallerMain cm = new CallerMain();
    cm.foo();
  }
}

class A{
  public void foo(){
    System.out.println("A - foo");
    System.out.println(this.getClass());//output- A
  }
}
```