# Getting information about class inside its method

Tags: java

I'm having one function which is inherited in other classes. What I would like in that function is to get current class name in which is running. For example:

```
public class A {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(this.class.getName()); // I know this syntax is incorrect
    }
}

public class B extends A {
}
```

I would like when I call instance of class A,  for function foo() to print "A", and when running foo from instance of class B to write "B", without having to explicitly overload foo() function.

EDIT:
As Arvind said it solution I was looking for was:

```
this.getClass().getName()
```

Comment: Smells like an `X Y Problem`. What are you trying to achieve here, that makes polymorphism impossible?

Comment: Take a look at this `-->`  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1696565/235710

Comment: u may try this: System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());