# How can I get the name of a class, with an static Method (not with Exception)

Tags: java, reflection

I have to write a method which can be called in any class to get the name of the class which is calling the method. The return type should be `Class`, so I can use it for another method. So that is what I have right now, but I think its not a clean code. Maybe there is way to use

```
public class Vlogger{
    public static Class getInstance() throws ClassNotFoundException {
       String className =new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();
       return Class.forName(className);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current stack trace in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/get-current-stack-trace-in-java)

Comment: [I´m gonna quote the accepted answer:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696551/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-class-in-java) "But in real there should be no need for this, unless for some logging purposes, because this is a fairly expensive task. What is it, the problem for which you think that this is the solution? We may come up with -much- better suggestions.".

Comment: Yes youre right  I need to code a logging Class, with use A log class and a class wich builds the logs for the sysout

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? You can use log4j or slf4j/logback, slf4j/log4j , ...

Comment: I already use these: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; and org.slf4j.Logger

Comment: What do you need the stacktrace for, then? Do you want to log the caller of a (or some) specific method?

Comment: so when I am Using the current Logger I do it like that:

Comment: private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResourceStatements.class);

Comment: now I want to code a Class , wich do this and prepare the finish sysout statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no clean code for this task yet.

Be prepared to replace it, when [Java 9](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/?java/lang/StackWalker.html) has been released:

```
public class Vlogger{
    public static Class getInstance() {
       return StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE)
                         .getCallerClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be something about it in Java 9 here: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/259