# Get class name in a static way in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, static, classname

This is a follow up to [more general and similar question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696551/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-class-in-java)

In **Java 8** I can get class name called the method using [new Exception](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/master/src/jorphan/src/main/java/org/apache/jorphan/logging/LoggingManager.java)

> ```
> String className = new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();
> ```

But can I get class name in a static way?

*edit*

If I'm inside a different class's method and want to know the class called my method

Comment: Based on your comment to an answer below, is it safe to say that you're asking for a way to statically determine the classname of a calling class from within a method call?

Comment: @gus yes exactly

Comment: I don't think you can do that statically, but you can do it without having to create an `Exception` using `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();`

Comment: "know the class called my method" how should that work in a static way? A method can be called from a lot of other classes, only what I can think of is that each calling class must pass its classname as an argument to the called method

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger StackWalker in Java 9

Comment: @user7294900 the name itself `...Walker` suggest that it is not statically or in a "static way", more like dynamic   (but maybe I am misunderstanding what is meant by static)

Comment: @NathanHughes I want dynamically on runtime to know class mame

Comment: dynamically? wasn't it static? I would think they are opposite, am I really that bad at English?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger get class name on runtime using static method

Comment: never mind I probably also have a different understanding what a `static` method is (sure not `element.getClassName()`)  and its too late for me to get it anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Example for getting the class name of the calling class in a static way from another class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        example();
    }

    public static void example() {
        B b = new B();
        b.methodB();
    }
}

class B {
    public void methodB(){
        System.out.println("I am methodB");
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement element = stackTrace[2];
        System.out.println("I was called by a method named: " + element.getMethodName());
        System.out.println("That method is in class: " + element.getClassName());
    }
}
```

#### Example for getting the fully qualified class name in static way:

`MyClass.class.getName();`

Comment: I'm inside a different class's method and want to know the class called my method

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please let me know if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

The Java9+ technique of getting the call stack uses `StackWalker`. The equivalent of [Ritesh Puj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58224814/1441122) using `StackWalker` is as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        example();
    }

    public static void example() {
        B b = new B();
        b.methodB();
    }
}

class B {
    public void methodB(){
        System.out.println("I am methodB");
        StackWalker.getInstance()
                   .walk(frames -> frames.skip(1).findFirst())
                   .ifPresent(frame -> {
                        System.out.println("I was called by a method named: " + frame.getMethodName());
                        System.out.println("That method is in class: " + frame.getClassName());
                   });
    }
}
```

The advantage of using `StackWalker` is that it generates stack frames lazily. This avoids the expense that `Thread.getStackTrace()` incurs when creating a large array of stack frames. Creating the full stack trace is especially wasteful if the call stack is deep, and if you only want to look up a couple frames, as in this example.

Comment: Is there Java 8 equivalent?

Comment: @user7294900 No, StackWalker was introduced in Java 9. Probably the best Java 8 way is shown in Ritesh Puj's answer, which is to get the full stack trace.