# How to get caller class' logger

Tags: java, logging

I have a util class with static function `doSthAndLogIt()`.

Inside it I want to do something + logging.

My question is, without passing the logger as param in `doSthAndLogIt(Logger logger)`, is there a way to get the logger from the class that calls `doSthAndLogIt()`?

---

More context:

```java
public class UtilClz(){
  // I don't want to use UtilClz's own logger, as caller's info will be lost
  // Logger utilLogger = Logger.getLogger(UtilClz.class);

  public static void doSthAndLogIt(Runnable runnable){
    runnable.run();
    //do logging
    //callerLogger.info(...)
  };
}

public class Caller(){
  Logger callerLogger = Logger.getLogger(Caller.class);

  public void doIt(){
    UtilClz.doSthAndLogIt( () -> doSth() );
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve, is to somehow get `callerLogger` to log message in `UtilClz::doSthAndLogIt` without passing `callerLogger` in as function param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Get the caller class. To avoid duplication, see this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45811032/2170192

Step 2: Get logger by the caller class.

Comment: I think if I call `Logger.getLogger(Caller.class)` 10 times, only one logger instance is created, so there's no performance issue?

Comment: Exactly, if the logger (for a specific class) was already created, `Logger.getLogger()` will return the existing instance.